# System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderException: Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace ... found

Tags: wcf, http-headers

I have implemented an interface to an erp-system with WCF. The interface works fine nearly all the time. Every 2-3 weaks in the erp-system a deadlock occurs and then I get a System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderException when I try to read the answer. Somehow I get a success and a failure message from the erp-system an I can't read this. I have not enabled logging for the wcf right now.

How can I prevent this error? Can I interpret messages with multiple headers?

Complete error:

```
System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderException: Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' found.
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? Or some kind of workaround? I'm in a similar situation...

Comment: Sorry, not yet.

Comment: I'm experimenting the same issue with MS Dynamics AX. Since I don't know yet how to solve it I tried this workaround: As you say, the problem occurs when excepctions happend, you probably are catching those exceptions and returning a fancy message so the client doesn't get the error. (At this point, there must be a way to clean the "result buffer" so the exception info don't go as part of the response). But, if you don't catch the error, or if you retrhow the error with a another message (just for the fancy). The client will still get an exception that he must handle it, but there's no more "M

Comment: @opena854: I also have this problem with MS Dynamics AX! Maybe it is a problem with AX.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced encountered same error while working on aif services which is basically based on top of dotnet wcf services. My Service operation was returning a List DataContract of a type which itself  having a List DataContract as DataMember.

There was a problem in the code which resulted in corrupted response header

[image]

Here is complete metadata

```
<HMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContractHMPackageItemDefaultsContract: Dynamics.Ax.Application.HMPackageItemDefaultsContract>}
```

Items were not seperated by commas (,). due to a code glitch

```
contract = new HMPackageItemDefaultsContract();
switch (line.HMProductType)
{
    case HMInventType::Laboratory:

        hmLaboratoryDefault = HMLaboratoryDefault::findByPackageDefinitionLine(line);
        while select hmLaboratoryDefault
        {
            contract.parmCollectionDate(hmLaboratoryDefault.CollectionDate);
            contract.parmInstructionstoPatient(hmLaboratoryDefault.Instructions);
            contract.parmNotestoPharmacy(hmLaboratoryDefault.Notes);
            contract.parmSpecimenSource(hmLaboratoryDefault.HMSpecimenSource);

            list.addEnd(contract);
        }

    break;
```

contract was not being instantiated on each while iteration to add it to list.

Took me 3 hour to figure it out after doing compilation, cleaning up XPPIL and doing full cil.

I just figured out there is one more scenario where it fails, when you have DataMemberberContract returning enum type with a fixed set of items with their corresponding integer values and you returning an enum integer value out of bound.

WCF doesn't give any error message specific to the actual error, it just fails with below message

```
Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' found.
```

Hope it help folks out there who encounter such concealed exceptions.